# For an embedded client-server architecture, is node.js the best option?

Tags: node.js, embedded, client-server

We have an embedded box. The specs of the CPU is medium speed (600MHz) and RAM is between 512MB to 2GB depending on configuration. The system consists of data layer to process incoming data from hardware and needing to be displayed both remotely and on an HDMI output.

Seeing the remote aspect is as important as the local display, we have architected a client-server solution. For the server, it just needs to respond to requests for data. The data needs to come from the internals of another process (IPC interaction) and return it formatted for the client.

For the server we are thinking of using node.js. The data is spec'ed to be formatted into json messages, so using JavaScript and json is simple.

However, are there any better/other server options to consider?

The main requirement is the server can be extended to interact with the data process and be able to process and respond to requests.

We could write it ourselves, but feel that there must be usable tech to leverage already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*I am assuming that you need output as a webpage only.*

It depends.
If your team knows java/servlet well, you can do using simple jetty/servlet/jsp combination.

But if you have team good with javascript/node.js, go with it. Although, I am not sure about stability requirements you have, because node.js is quite stable but it haven't reached 1.0 yet.

Comment: Thanks - we just need to output json messages and not actual UI components or layouts, or anything like that - just data strings. Not a fan of java, would rather use a C/C++ based implementation as our embedded JVM is real slow.